# Is it possible to find out which files are setting/adding to environment variables, and their order of precedence?

Tags: environment-variables

Some of my environment variables (`$PATH`, `$MANPATH` and friends) are partially set up in different source files.

I find myself wishing for a command or method to quickly gather *what part*, in a specific environment variable, came from *what file*.

My $PATH, for instance, has obviously been set (added to) in `.bashrc`, `/etc/paths`, `/etc/paths.d/X11` … and I'm still looking for that last mysterious file which superfluously created a duplicate path definition in my `$PATH`.

It takes a good while to manually pinpoint the files that contribute to environment variables. There must be a useful way to bypass this unnecessary labor of tracing all the setters … or am I the only one thinking along these lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically `PATH` is set to an initial value in a highly system-dependent way by the program that logs you in ([`pam_env`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_env.html) is a common contributor), then `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` and files that they include go on to modify that value.

Remove any change to `PATH` in `.bashrc`, environment settings don't belong in `.bashrc`: see [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980).

First try logging in in text mode (e.g. with `ssh localhost`), as the session startup is a lot simpler than in graphics mode.

Put `set -x` at the beginning of `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`. The shell will print a trace of what it does on its standard error stream; look for assignments to `PATH` in the trace.

There is no notion of precedence to environment variable assignments: whoever assigns last wins.

Answer (score 6):

Your PATH can be set anywhere, not just in your .bashrc file. Most likely your system has a file,  `/etc/profile` and/or `/etc/profile.local` which sets a default path for all users on your system. User specific changes or additions to it might be set in your `.profile` file if they're not in your `.bashrc`, or you may just be using the default on your system.

If you want to makes changes that only affect you, I'd put them in your `.profile` using the following form:

`export PATH=/new/directory:$PATH`

thereby editing the current path rather than rewriting it entirely.

The "INVOCATION" section of `man bash` (or [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)) explains the difference between `.profile` and `.bashrc`, and so on, and which other files and read and in what order when you log in or start a shell.

Answer (score 1):

It is very unlikely that a mechanism for this exists.  Just think about how many ways there are to change the value of an env variable in the shell.

You may have some luck with `set -x` though.