# Why is my PATH not listed in my .bashrc file?

Tags: bash, path, profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to find out which files are setting/adding to environment variables, and their order of precedence?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4632/is-it-possible-to-find-out-which-files-are-setting-adding-to-environment-variable)

I am a Linux novice.  I would like to edit my PATH (which I am able to *view* using the command `$ echo $PATH`), but when I am in my root/home directory (`~`), it appears that the file **.bashrc** contains only the following text:

```
# Sample .bashrc for SuSE Linux
# Copyright (c) SuSE GmbH Nuernberg

# There are 3 different types of shells in bash: the login shell, normal shell
# and interactive shell. Login shells read ~/.profile and interactive shells
# read ~/.bashrc; in our setup, /etc/profile sources ~/.bashrc - thus all
# settings made here will also take effect in a login shell.
#
# NOTE: It is recommended to make language settings in ~/.profile rather than
# here, since multilingual X sessions would not work properly if LANG is over-
# ridden in every subshell.

# Some applications read the EDITOR variable to determine your favourite text
# editor. So uncomment the line below and enter the editor of your choice :-)
#export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
#export EDITOR=/usr/bin/mcedit

# For some news readers it makes sense to specify the NEWSSERVER variable here
#export NEWSSERVER=your.news.server

# If you want to use a Palm device with Linux, uncomment the two lines below.
# For some (older) Palm Pilots, you might need to set a lower baud rate
# e.g. 57600 or 38400; lowest is 9600 (very slow!)
#
#export PILOTPORT=/dev/pilot
#export PILOTRATE=115200

test -s ~/.alias && . ~/.alias || true
```

where I have opened **.bashrc** using the command `$ vi .bashrc`.

By the way, when I type the command

```
$ echo $PATH
```

I obtain the following output:

```
/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin:/usr/local/gromacs/bin:/export/home/adeyoung/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/opt/kde3/bin:/opt/intel/Compiler/11.0/074/bin/intel64:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin:/usr/lib/qt3/bin
```

Do you think that I am looking in the correct file for my PATH?  Thank you very much for your time.